# Display dropped image on Form

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

I have a C# app and i want it that when an Image is dropped on the form, A picturebox in the form displays the Image. I have tried this

```
    private void Form1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;   
    }

    private void Form1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics p = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        p.DrawImage((Image)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap), new Point(0, 10));
    }
```

But it doesn't work.

Pls what did i do wrong?

Comment: What is the sample app you used to drag the image from? Your code however doesn't work OK until you `Invalidate` your pictureBox1, you should use `Image` property instead like this: `pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap) e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);`

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work

Comment: Is there any exception?

Comment: @Precious1tj from where you dragging into form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are dragging from file.
Simple code for this will be such:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.AllowDrop = true;
        this.DragDrop += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.Form1_DragDrop);
        this.DragEnter += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.Form1_DragEnter);
    } 
    private void Form1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy; 
        }
        else
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
        }
    }

    private void Form1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] filex = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
        if (filex.Length > 0)
        { 
                pictureBox1.ImageLocation = filex[0]; 

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i truly hope this is not the solution but you didn't gave much information so i'll start here and we'll go as you give us more information.
when you toke this sample did you bind it to the proper events?
as in:

```
this.DragDrop += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.Form1_DragDrop);
this.DragEnter += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.Form1_DragEnter);
```

also, on initializing, did you do:

```
AllowDrop = true;
```